# Measure Application Load Times?

Tags: performance

Anyone know a way to measure application load times? I've looked at instruments but having a hard time pinning down the statistic/event I should be looking for.

I want to measure how long it takes for the app to finish loading, (the window appears) etc

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How precise of a measurement do you need?

Comment: Just in miliseconds. Essentially comparing the loading times of different browsers.